# PowerShell Excel file

Tags: excel, powershell

Can you please help me with below requirement in PowerShell.

Input for Power shell script is — Excel File which consists single column , column name is EmpName.

Sample values are

```
AARON, JEFFERY
AARON, KARINA
ABBATE, JOSEPH L
ABBATEMARCO, JAMES J
ABDALLAH, ZAID
```

Output is: Create a new excel file with 2 columns EmpName and EmpShortName. Here Name columns values are same as input file and ShortName value are first char of first name and all characters of last name.

Example:

```
EmpName EmpShortName
AARON, JEFFERY jaaron
AARON, KARINA kaaron
ABBATE, JOSEPH L jabbate
ABBATEMARCO, JAMES J jabbatemarco
ABDALLAH, ZAID zabdallah
```

I tried this

```
# Specify the path to the Excel file and the WorkSheet Name
$FilePath = "D:\2018\Book2.xlsx"
$SheetName = "Sheet1"

# Create an Object Excel.Application using Com interface
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application

# Disable the 'visible' property so the document won't open in excel
$objExcel.Visible = $false

# Open the Excel file and save it in $WorkBook
$WorkBook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($FilePath)

# Load the WorkSheet 'Sheet1'
$WorkSheet = $WorkBook.sheets.item($SheetName)

[pscustomobject][ordered]@{
EmpName = $WorkSheet.Range("A1").Text }
```

But getting error in the last line. Once it worked need to write a logic get another column form EmpName column

Comment: Please read [ask]. This site does not exist to do your homework for you. You can get help if you ask a question about **a specific programming problem**. If you have no idea how to go about your task get back to the person who assigned it to you.

Comment: I am trying it but got stuck

Comment: Now that you did show that you tried and are stuck on a very specific problem, you just should add the error message you get and you are likely to get help. I reverted my down-vote and vote-to-close.

Comment: its returning only column A1 value, trying to return all the values and along with new column .. Do I need to create any loop here to loop through all the rows or Is there easy way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `.Range("A1").CurrentRegion` to select all the cells adjacent to `A1` not just `A1` itself.

```powershell
$Worksheet.Range('A1').CurrentRegion | Where-Object {
    $_.text -notmatch "EmpName"
} | ForEach-Object {
    $name = $_.text
    $split = $name -split ", "
    [pscustomobject]@{
        EmpName = $name
        EmpShortName = $split[1][0]+$split[0]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You said that the data was in an Excel file. Is it actually an Excel file or is it a .csv file? If it's .csv, then importing the data is easy with [Import-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Import-Csv?view=powershell-6). Either way, once you have the data imported, use [Select-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-6) and *calculated properties* to restructure the data. Finally use `Export-Csv` to save the output file. If it is a .csv file, then a simple solution might be

```
 Import-Csv  employees.csv -Header last,first |
    Select-Object -Property `
        @{n="EmpName";      e={$_.first + " " + $_.last }},
        @{n="EmpShortName"; e={ $_.first[0] + $_.Last }} |
            Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation employees_updated.csv
```

Comment: input file is actually EXCEL file  and when I ran this power shell script , in the file row1 displayed as "#TYPE Selected.System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject"

Comment: "#TYPE ... " is just a comment saying what type the exported objects originally were. You can suppress it using the `-NoTypeInformation` parameter on `Export-Csv`. I've updated my answer to reflect this.